# Angular detect if user coming from webview

Tags: javascript, angular, webview

The first API call in my Angular 8 application when it initializes, is a 'GET' call to a CDN to get some images,

(example: `https://imagescdn/images`)

is there anyway to detect if the user is opening the Angular App using an Android / IOS webview? as in that case I need to change the domain name for that first API call in the Angular App

from:
`https://imagescdn/images`
to:
`https://anotherImagesCDN/images`